# How to get the details of a module function with repl in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

By using tab in Nodejs REPL I could get the information of a module, e.g. module url like below. But what if I want to know the details of a function in it? e.g. I want to know what parameters the url.parse function need, and the details of them. Can I get this information offline from REPL?

```
> var url = require('url');
undefined
> url.
url.__defineGetter__      url.__defineSetter__      url.__lookupGetter__
url.__lookupSetter__      url.__proto__             url.constructor
url.hasOwnProperty        url.isPrototypeOf         url.propertyIsEnumerable
url.toLocaleString        url.toString              url.valueOf

url.URL                   url.Url                   url.domainToASCII
url.domainToUnicode       url.format                url.originFor
url.parse                 url.resolve               url.resolveObject
```

Comment: No you cant do that reliable. You can get the information of the function signature, but the number of arguments that are needed is only enforced by function implementation itself. Some functions can be called with different number of arguments and types. So you can only know how you have to use the function reading the docs.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks for the direct, I finally found the offline-docs(https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-docs) is a good solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling url.parse.toString() this will give you the 'source' of the function.

In case of url.parse this technique returns (in node 6.9.2 on Ubuntu)

`'function urlParse(url, parseQueryString, slashesDenoteHost) {\n  if (url instanceof Url) return url;\n\n  var u = new Url();\n  u.parse(url, parseQueryString, slashesDenoteHost);\n  return u;\n}'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the REPL could not give the details of a function, and maybe I should check out the docs. The offline-docs(https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-docs) seems good for me.